# I just updated UI on worker thread without a problem and I don't know why

Tags: android, kotlin

I know updating UI on worker thread is not recommended by Google. I tried writing a demo using **Java** and it crashed as expected. However, when I switched to **Kotlin**, I found, to my surprise, that even I'm not on the UI thread, I can update UI without a crash. How is that happening?

My code in Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Thread {
            Thread.sleep(5000)
            myText.text = "updated text"
        }.start()
    }
}
```

The main layout file contains only a plain TextView with id "myText".
My android sdk version is 29.

I'm thinking maybe Kotlin does some thread switching behind the scene or Google changed the rules(not likely) but that's just my guess.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: And if you create release build and run this code, your app will crash

Comment: Can you try printing thread id outside the block and inside the block? It should be different ideally. I tried running this snippet and found out it was giving thread id as 1 both outside/inside the block which means thread shift didn't happen (not every time it happened).

Comment: Are you sure, it gets updated??. i  tried running the same but nothing happened.Crash didn't happen but log inside the lambda block got executed. I had set everything to 29 also.

Comment: @PrashantJha I tried printing thread id inside and outside the Thread {} block using Thread.currentThread().id and got 2 different ids. The UI updating did happen in the worker thread.

Comment: @RishabhRitweek Yes the textview got updated here in 5s and the app didn't crash. You put the update statement in lambda block and the textview didn't get updated? weird

Comment: I got this error when run this code use sdk version 29 CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @UuuUuu Really? Are you running the code on emulator or real phone? system version?

Comment: Android studio emulator api 28 and 29

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update on ui thread with Java. You can continue with this logic as follows.

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is
> the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current
> thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue
> of the UI thread.

for java

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something on UiThread
    }
});
```

for kotlin

```
runOnUiThread({
    Log.i(TAG, "This is run")
    object : Runnable {                    // This whole expression
        override fun run() {               // returns an object which
            Log.i(TAG, "runOnUiThread")    // is a Runnable, but does
        }                                  // not at any point invoke
    }                                      // its "run" method
    Log.i(TAG, "And so is this")
})
```

Comment: Useful information! But I'm still confused why the code didn't crash on updating UI in workder thread...

Answer (score 0):

Logically Thread is associated with the current main thread so there should be no issue if you change UI element in Thread whereas if you create another child thread using handler or runnable then it would not allow you to change UI elements inside those threads current thread you mentioned is actually the main thread not another.
Just like coroutine there is DISPATCHER.MAIN you code is exactly like that

Comment: I printed thread ids inside and outside the Thread {} block and got 2 different ids. I think that means they are running in different threads?

Comment: Unless you do thread = new thread then ids should be different if you access the same thread then should get same ids